# Does $u(x,t)=0$ on $(x,t)\in(-\delta,\delta)\times{\Bbb R}$ imply $u\equiv 0$ for wave equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider the wave equation
>   $$
> u_{tt}=u_{xx}.
> $$
>   Suppose $u(x,t)=0$ on $(x,t)\in(-\delta,\delta)\times{\Bbb R}$ for some $\delta>0$. Do I have $u\equiv 0$?

---

I thought that this could be done using the domain of dependence. But it turns out that I am not able to go further.

Also, if $\delta=0$, then $u(x,t)=xt$ satisfies all the conditions but obviously $u\equiv0$ is not true.  This seems to be a key point, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v(x,t)=u(t,x)$. Note this is also a solution of the wave equation.

[D'Alembert's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) for solution    expresses $v$ in terms of $v$ and $v_t$ at time $t=0$.  Under your assumption, both of these are identically zero.

Comment: I don't see how the initial data is identically $0$. Under the assumption, I only see $u(x,0)=0$ for $-\delta<x<\delta$.

Comment: @Jack The variables $x$ and $t$ are interchangeable, so I implicitly swapped them. Edited.